# Vote to "Leave Open" from question screen

Tags: feature-request

Could the "close" option link for questions include the facility for directly voting "leave open" on a question that has a "close" vote and is on the reivew stack?

This would be useful if the question has clearly been updated to satisfactory condition. I'm thinking of questions that are voted for closure due to poor layout or information that is then corrected, so within a few  minutes to an hour or so  of being asked.

Comment: This meta.SE post seems related: [Allow voting “Vote to not close” from the question without being in a review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151476). See also other posts [linked there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/151476).

Comment: What is that feature supposed to do? A "leave open" vote currently only has a meaning for questions inside the CV review process, which are not all question with a close vote, and often not those that got improved to satisfactory condition. Thus it is unclear what you propose.

Comment: @quid I would see this as a quick way to clear those questions out of the CV review queue.

Comment: What if they are not inside? If you want this only for question insider the queue than say so; there were other proposals with different functionality.