# Finding a question's "review" page when you're not reviewing close proposals

Tags: discussion, support, review

Click on "review", then on "close votes" and you can vote on a question. Then on another. Then on another. In an earlier posting, I remarked that you can't choose from a list. If my only motive were to get paid by the hour for voting on these things, then that would be appropriate; otherwise it has all the appropriateness of approaching a stranger in a public square and giving him an order and expecting obedience.

My present question is this: You're looking at a posted question, NOT at "review", and you see that someone has voted to close it. How do you go straight from there to the page you'd see in the review queue to cast a vote on whether to close it or leave it open?

Comment: "If my only motive were to get paid by the hour for voting on these things, then that would be appropriate; otherwise it has all the appropriateness of approaching a stranger in a public square and giving him an order and expecting obedience." If you do not want to review, just don't. If you do volunteer to review, don't complain you are ask to perform the task you volunteered to do.

Comment: "How do you go straight from there to the page you'd see in the review queue to case a vote on whether to close it or leave it open?" That's not supported, as far as I know. In the former case it'd be rather pointless too; just vote on the question.

Comment: @quid : How do I do that?

Comment: How do you do what?

Comment: @quid : Your sweeping failure to understand any what you quoted in your first comment is breathtaking.

Comment: @quid : How do you "just vote on the question" when you're not on its page that you reach by going to "review" and then to "close questions" and then clicking through until that one comes up? As far as I can see, you can do that ONLY if you want to vote to CLOSE the question.

Comment: I think I understand it quite well. Instead, it seems you misunderstand the purpose of the review queues.

Comment: How do you know about the question in the first place? Presumably as you are on that questions page. Or at least have a link to it. Either way you obviously can vote to close on the question itself. *If* your point is that this works only for vote to close and not vote to leave open, then yes that's correct, but it'd be a bit weird that you feel the need to point it out given that I wrote  "**In the former case** [that is, vote to close] it'd be rather pointless too; just vote on the question."

Comment: ok, That clarifies what you meant by "the former case": it referred back to the phrase "whether to close it or leave it open?". That phrase was quite vague.

Comment: What else could it have referred to?

Comment: @quid : You say "If you do not want to review, just don't." That seems to disregard the possibility that you don't want to review except as the occasion arises. Maybe you don't want to spend your time repairing cars, but there is one car that you want repaired. That can actually happen, and does.

Comment: @quid : It might also be that you're looking over a bunch of cars wondering if some would be worth repairing, and you notice three of the $50$ are. That's different from a situation where can't see those three until you've carefully assessed $25$ others that are in the queue ahead of it.

Comment: I can only repeat that "it seems you misunderstand the purpose of the review queues." If you are treating questions as you come across them you are simply not engaging in 'review'. Your actual point seems to be that you wish to cast 'leave open' votes without actually participating in review. Again, to the best of my knowledge, this is not supported.

Comment: If you want a list of questions, you can use 'history'. You can also search for an individual questions there. (The drawback is that it is not always clear if the review is still ongoing or not.) Clicking on an others user review decision will give you the review page. This is a bit tedious but again that's by design as one is not really supposed to cherry-pick reviews (beyond the basic filtering provided). Of course skipping is always an option. Yet, after the review is completed a link to  the report shows up in the questions timeline.

Comment: @quid : It's not without participating in review; rather it's without participating in review except on questions where the occasion arises, or at times when you otherwise choose to participate in review.

Comment: @quid : What if people did not "cherry-pick" the questions they answer? What would become of stackexchange?

Comment: For the third time, the intent is that one can cast leave open votes only while one works through the review queue (viz. participates in review), and not on questions that one happens to see otherwise. Arguably this could also be different, but it is as it is, and that's afaik fully intentional.

Comment: @quid : To say it's fully intentional suggests that someone had in mind some reason why it ought to be done that way. What could that be?

Comment: Your post is perhaps not the same but still rather similar to this feature request: [Vote to “Leave Open” from question screen](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25946) I will also add somewhat related discussion from another per-site-meta: [How to vote to “Leave Open” without going through every question on the Close queue](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10356)

Comment: And also this feature request on meta.SE seems basically the same as yours: [Allow us to access a post's Reviews directly from the post itself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174789) It is marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Comment: See for example the post linked in @Martin's last comment for evidence that it is fully intentionally and some explanation of the rational behind it.

Comment: I see this is closely related to an earlier post of yours, Michael.  Very much so: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26860/getting-list-of-questions-in-review-queues.

Comment: @amWhy : Definitely it's related, not only in that both postings are about my proposals to improve the review process.

Comment: You ask duplicate questions on meta so often, that I suggest that when one specific user repeats a crusade in more than one post, the question should be deleted, and the questioner who repeatedly posts the same question, be sanctioned.

Comment: @amWhy : I post on meta when the occasion arises, and always with some reluctance.

Comment: That's futile, you should know better.

Comment: @quid : Note that above I wrote "@quid : You say 'If you do not want to review, just don't.' That seems to disregard the possibility that you don't want to review except as the occasion arises. Maybe you don't want to spend your time repairing cars, but there is one car that you want repaired. That can actually happen, and does." And you did not attempt to answer that. Then you said one could "cherry pick" which questions one votes on, as if such "cherry picking" were a bad thing, and$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$then I wrote "What if people did not "cherry-pick" the questions they answer? What would become of stackexchange?", and you made no attempt to answer that. I am beginning to suspect that you think one is not reviewing in good faith unless one is willing to go through a list of all review questions. If that were the case, then why is a limited degree of filtering allowed?

Comment: I had seen it then but at that time felt replying was not productive. The problem is that we mean different things by "to review" (in the context of an SE site). To me it basically exclusively means perusing the queues and thus your analogies do not make sense with this meaning of reviewing. One reviews what one gets shown by the system. When you come across a question on the main site and decide to consider it and do something about it you are not reviewing the question in my narrow sense.

Comment: Some actions are limited to those that participate in reviewing (in this sense): leave open, leave closed, recommend deletion are those that come to mind. Could this also be different? Sure. But it is as it is. It is not so much "that [I] think one is not reviewing in good faith unless one is willing to go through a list of all review questions" instead I think that one is not reviewing, period.

Comment: That said, indeed I felt your actual question is how you could manage vote to leave open on questions of which you noticed they had in your opinion unjustified votes to close, in order to try to prevent closure. In my opinion, this is not really in the spirit of the review queues. But, if you limit it to a leave open here and there, well, I guess worse things happen on the site. So I even gave you instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Ah right the cherry picking and filtering is still open. Well, it is just a matter of degree. One is somewhat free to narrow down to optimize for ones expertise and interests but the general task still stays to review questions that *somebody else* or the system has flagged up as needing review. Put differently to me reviewing in our context is  having a 'second look' at posts *preselected* by somebody else (or the system). If you come across a post by yourself it's not a review. If you do not want to do this fine, just don't. But some actions are intended to be reserved to those that do.

Comment: @quid : You wrote: "If you do not want to review, just don't." I think that comment is disrespectful. In the '50 in the South, negroes were ordered to step to the back of the bus. And you came along and told them "If you don't want to ride the bus, then don't." The way the review queue is run is disrespectful to users. I _do_ want to review, but I want to review by reviewing, not by being treated disrespectfully.

Comment: I am sorry that you find my comment disrespectful. Your comparison strikes me as not apt on various levels to put it mildly. For one thing, the review queues work in the same way for basically everybody.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Giving you the benefit of the doubt: The case you mention was not problematic because of how inconvenient the back of the bus was, as in the issue of the voting queue here, but because people were segregated by ethnicity. If this is unclear to you, I'd recommend never ever discussing race relations with anyone. People might get a very bad impression of you.

Comment: @quid : The review queue functions in a manner that is disrespectful to its users.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : You're being very silly. The thing that was to be analogous is that in both cases the system functions in a way that is disrespectful to users.

Answer (score 5):

> You're looking at a posted question, NOT at "review", and you see that someone has voted to close it. How do you go straight from there to the page you'd see in the review queue to cast a vote on whether to close it or leave it open?

Summarizing the comments, this is not supported for *users* (as opposed to moderators) and this is *intentional* as documented by, e.g., the declined feature request [Allow us to access a post's Reviews directly from the post itself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174789/allow-us-to-access-a-posts-reviews-directly-from-the-post-itself)  (hat-tip to Martin) or more recently [Should the new timeline view show links to review items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items) were even action was taken to *remove links to ongoing reviews from the timeline* of a post. (Instead, completed reviews were put into the timeline.)

There are some workarounds to find reviews if one must. (Of course if one wishes to vote to close there is not much point in insisting to do so via the review menu.)

Preparatory step: Check the timeline of the question to get an idea if there even is a review ongoing; it might already be completed. (Completed reviews are in the timeline.)

Option 1 (for high-rep users only): Look through  'history' on the review page to find the post via its title (one can use text-search features of ones browser to simplify this). Click on the record of the action taken (not the title) to get to the question's review page.

Option 2: Calibrate the filter to match the relevant question by selecting the close reason already in place (click on 'close' on the question to find out which one(s) was already selected) and by filtering for a (rare) tag on the question.  Usually that should not leave that many, and skip does the rest.

To reiterate, these are workarounds and to search for a question in the review queue to vote on it is not really in the spirit of the review queues.

Comment: What do you mean by "timeline"? Are you talking about the question's edit history?

Comment: There is a page called "Timeline for" associated to each post, and I am talking about this page. It can  be accessed  via `/posts/{postid}/timeline` (there is no link to it).

Comment: @MichaelHardy You can find links to some basic information on the timeline in [the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info). In particular, see: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826)